# Setting config during Linux kernel getting error input in flex scanner failed

Tags: linux-kernel

I am getting the following error when I try to set config like below,

```
$ make ARCH=arm bcm_defconfig
```

I get the following error,

```
input in flex scanner failed
make[1]: *** [bcm_defconfig] Error 2
make: *** [bcm_defconfig] Error 2
```

I get this error for all ARCH=arm configs. Don't get this for other ARCH values.

Comment: What is version of the kernel you built? Is it vanilla kernel(taken from kernel.org) or not? `bcm_defconfig` is located under `arch/arm/configs/bcm_defconfig` isn't it? This file is relatively small(~150 lines including comments), can you check that it is not broken?

Comment: Yes, it is the Vanilla kernel downloaded yesterday from kernel.org. Yes bcm_defconfig exists at arch/arm/configs/bcm_defconfig. It does not look broken. Is there a way to confirm it. bcm_defconfig has 142 lines.

Strange thing is make ARCH=arm <any_defconfig> is giving me input in flex scanner failed error.

Comment: Yes, it looks very strange. Even if some lines in `bcm_config` are invalid, configuration just warns about these lines, but otherwise succeed. Are you have kernel sources on *local* linux filesystem(like ext4)? Building kernel on some sort of *remote* filesystem may be reason of spurious fails.

Comment: If you are cross-compiling, I wonder why you have not defined the `CROSS_COMPILE=` env. variable pointing to the cross gcc...